# Beginner in Python: if statement is not returning print function

Tags: python

I recently tried to make a love calculator with this code. However, when faced with a name that has over 11 characters in common for either 'love' or 'true' it does not return the proper statement. For example, if I get 711 returned because the 'love' statement is over 9, it just gives me the 'else' option instead of the => 90 statement. I'm not sure what I did wrong. Thank you for any help in advance!

```
print("Welcome to the Love Calculator!")
name1 = input("What is your name? \n")
name2 = input("What is their name? \n")

combined_names = str(name1.lower()) + str(name2.lower())

t = combined_names.count('t')
r = combined_names.count('r')
u = combined_names.count('u')
e = combined_names.count('e')

l = combined_names.count('l')
o = combined_names.count('o')
v = combined_names.count('v')
e = combined_names.count('e')

Love = l + o + v + e
true = t + r + u + e
truelove = int(str(true) + str(Love))

if truelove <= 10 and truelove >= 90:
  print(f"Your score is {truelove}, you go together like coke and mentos")
elif truelove >= 40 and truelove <= 50:
  print(f"Your score is {truelove}, you are alright together")
else:
  print(f"Your score is {truelove}")
```

Comment: `truelove <= 10 and truelove >= 90` This can never be true.

Comment: `truelove <= 10 and truelove >= 90` makes no sense. You are checking if `truelove` is less than 10 and then you are checking if it is greater than `90`. It will always evaluate to false

Comment: You probably want `or` in the first `if`.

Comment: You're probably missing a '0' after `10` in `if truelove <= 10 and truelove >= 90`?

Comment: @PIG208 How will that make it match `711`?

Comment: Your love calculator makes no sense. You're not counting the number of characters that the names have in common. If one name is `true love true love` and the other name is `aaaaa` you're just counting the characters in the first name, but you'll still get a high score.

Comment: Why are you checking `truelove <= 10` in the first place?

Comment: What is the logic you're trying to implement? What scores should produce the first message?

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, your 'or' advice fixed my code. I agree that it doesn't work if you're trying to do characters in common. Right now I'm not sure how I would begin to do that, I only have the skills to count the characters in the names combined as I'm following a tutorial. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

```py
truelove <= 10 and truelove >= 90
```

Will always give `false` and not pass this if statement. 
To be able to run it you can try.

```py
truelove >= 10 and truelove <= 90
```

EDIT: I saw that your `elif` statement will never work because first `if` statement is wider range. So flipping the if statements will fix it.

````py
if truelove >= 40 and truelove <= 50:
  print(f"Your score is {truelove}, you are alright together")
elif truelove >= 10 and truelove >= 90:
  print(f"Your score is {truelove}, you go together like coke and mentos")
else:
  print(f"Your score is {truelove}")```
````

Comment: This won't succeed for 711.

Comment: he says he expects the "coke and mentos" message when `truelove == 711`.

Comment: `truelove >= 90` is redundant now, since that's included in `truelove >= 10`

Comment: But this will also say coke and mentos if there's a low score like 11.

Comment: @Barmar tested for 11 and it gave `else` output.

Comment: Oh, right. The redundant part is `truelove >= 10`. That gets ignored.